# Is there any word or phrase for providing a way/solution just for now?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there any word or phrase for "providing a way/solution for now/for the nonce"?

Example:

> We seek a theory that help us explain A and B. Theory T seems to help
> us explain A for now, but we haven't yet examine T to see if it has
> any problem and if it can explain B too.

What is the verb/phrasal verb to say the for-now service that T provide for us?

Comment: You could say "a stop-gap solution" or "we can use Theory T as a stop-gap for now".

Comment: @RozennKeribin I am looking for a verb/phrasal verb. Question edited.

Comment: *Interim* solution could work here.

Comment: I don't understand part of your question. What do you mean by "providing a way/solution for ... [*the nonce*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nonce)"?

Comment: @Lawrence for the nonce=for the present time.

Comment: Could be a _heuristic_ or _rule of thumb_.

Comment: The requirements were altered by an edit in such a way as to invalidate the answer then accepted. I've reconciled by changing back to the original. No single- or multi-word verb has been offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're looking for is a ***stop gap*** solution:

> **stop gap** a temporary way of dealing with a problem or satisfying a need
>
> [**stop gap**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stopgap) something that serves as a temporary expedient

Answer (score 1):

If a particular theory is to be adopted provisionally, subject to further investigation, it can be described as a working hypothesis.

A short-term practical solution, as opposed to a theory, can be called a tactical solution, which can be contrasted with a strategic solution.

Comment: OP has naughtily rendered your answer one for the past.